# Understanding isomorphic strings algorithm

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I am understanding the following code to find if the strings are isomorphic or not. The code uses two hashes `s_dict` and `t_dict` respectively. I am assuming the strings are of same length.

```
def isIsomorphic(s, t):
    s_dict = {}
    t_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] in s_dict.keys() and s_dict[s[i]] != t[i]:
            return False
        if t[i] in t_dict.keys() and t_dict[t[i]] != s[i]:
            return False
        s_dict[s[i]] = t[i]
        t_dict[t[i]] = s[i]
    return True
```

Now, if I modify the above code such that only one hash `s_dict()` is used, then also it gives desired results to my limited test cases. The modified code is as follows:

```
def isIsomorphic(s, t):
    s_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] in s_dict.keys() and s_dict[s[i]] != t[i]:
            return False
        s_dict[s[i]] = t[i]
    return True
```

What are the test cases in which the above modified code will fail? Is my understanding of the isomorphic strings wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple example, your code doesn't work on s='ab',t='aa'.

Basically you have to have both way to be isomorphic. Your code only checked that t can be modified from s, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

This was kind of fun to look at. Just for kicks, here's my solution using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

def get_idx_count(word):
    """Turns a word into a series of tuples (idx, consecutive_chars)

    "aabbccaa" -> [[(0, 2), (3, 2)], [(1, 2)], [(2, 2)]]
    """
    lst = defaultdict(list)
    for idx, (grp, val) in enumerate(groupby(word)):
        lst[grp].append((idx, sum(1 for _ in val)))
    return sorted(list(lst.values()))

def is_isomorphic(a, b):
    return get_idx_count(a) == get_idx_count(b)

is_isomorphic('aabbcc', 'bbddcc')  # True
is_isomorphic('aabbaa', 'bbddcc')  # False
```

Rather than building the lists, I feel like I could do something more like:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

def is_isomorphic(a, b):
    a_idxs, b_idxs = defaultdict(set), defaultdict(set)
    for idx, ((a_grp, a_vals), (b_grp, b_vals)) in enumerate(zip(groupby(a), groupby(b))):
        if sum(1 for _ in a_vals) != sum(1 for _ in b_vals):
            return False
            # ensure sequence is of same length
        if a_grp in a_idxs and b_idxs[b_grp] != a_idxs[a_grp] or\
           b_grp in b_idxs and a_idxs[a_grp] != b_idxs[b_grp]:
            return False
            # ensure previous occurrences are matching groups
        a_idxs[a_grp].add(idx)
        b_idxs[b_grp].add(idx)
        # save indexes for future checks
    return True
```

But I haven't had a chance to test that whatsoever. It does, however, have the likelihood of exiting early, rather than having to build all the lists and comparing them at the end. It also skips a few sets of sorting that shouldn't be necessary anyway, except that we're pulling from dicts, so bleh. Pretty sure `list.sort` is faster than saving to to a `collections.OrderedDict`. I think.

Comment: Could hash not do a better job while comparing instead of array?

Comment: @deep yep these were fairly quick and dirty. It was just fun to play with algorithms. I haven't done any of that in...well forever! Edited to use a hashtable instead in my second function

Comment: @deep and indeed:
Hashes: TRUE: 4.788953999650403e-06
        FALSE:1.6380690003643394e-06
Lists:  TRUE: 4.809526000371989e-06
        FALSE:1.6906679998101026e-06

Comment: Note that your solution is about twice as fast in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for Isomorphic String problem in Python:

Solution #1 (the fastest one):

```
def isometric_strings_translate(str1: str, str2: str) -> bool:
    trans = str.maketrans(str1, str2)
    return str1.translate(trans) == str2
```

Solution #2 (using set):

```
def isometric_strings_set(str1: str, str2: str) -> bool:
    return len(set(zip(str1, str2))) == len(set(str1))
```

Solution #3 (using dictionary):

```
def isometric_strings_dict(str1: str, str2: str) -> bool:
    map = {}
    for s1, s2 in zip(str1, str2):
        if map.setdefault(s1, s2) != s2:
            return False
    return True
```

[Here you can view full code.](https://github.com/vlad-bezden/py.checkio/blob/master/electronic_station/isomorphic_strings.py)

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about it without maps or dictionaries can help you understand:

```
def isIso(x,y):
  if len(x) != len(y):
    return False
  for i in range(len(x)):
    count = 0
    if x.count(x[i]) != y.count(y[i]):
      return False
  return True
```