# isomorphic python algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm

Question:
Given two strings s and t, determine if they are isomorphic.

Two strings are isomorphic if the characters in s can be replaced to get t.

All occurrences of a character must be replaced with another character while preserving the order of characters. No two characters may map to the same character but a character may map to itself.

My code:

```
def isIsomorphic(self, s, t):
    # write your code here
    remap = dict()
    if s == t:
        return True
    if len(s) !=  len(t):
        return False
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] not in remap.keys() and t[i] in remap.values():
            return False
        elif s[i] not in remap.keys():
            remap[s[i]] = t[i]
        else:
            if remap[s[i]] != t[i]:
                return False
    return True
```

error hint:
   Your code ran too much time than we expected. Check your time complexity. Time limit exceeded usually caused by infinite loop if your time complexity is the best.

Pls ask how i improve my code

Comment: Could you please use the correct formatting (hitting the code button with your code highlighted) so we can easily read your question?

Comment: sorry, I am a newer, I will notice next time

Comment: Is it allowed to remap multiple characters to the same character? In other words, are `ab` and `cc` isomorphic? What about `ab` and `bb`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey No two characters may map to the same character but a character may map to itself. seems to imply ab and cc would not be isometric

Comment: @JoranBeasley  thank u very much

Comment: Feel like this one-liner: `return list(map(s.find, s)) == list(map(t.find, t))`

Answer (score 5):

The strings will be isomorphic if the number of unique characters in each string is the same as the number of unique pairs of corresponding characters between them (they also have to be the same length).

So this function will do it concisely and much faster:

```
def isIsomorphic(w1,w2) : 
    if len(w1) != len(w2): return False
    return len(set(w1)) == len(set(w2)) == len(set(zip(w1,w2)))
```

[EDIT] 3.3 seconds on my computer for 1 million iterations of a pair of 25 character strings (vs 12 seconds for Aran-Fey's updated code).

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is to *normalize* your strings

```
import re,string
def normalize(s):
    key={}
    def replace_ltr(match):
        ltr = match.group(1)
        if ltr not in key:
           key[ltr] = string.printable[len(key)]
        return key[ltr]
    return re.sub("([a-zA-Z])",replace_ltr,s)

print normalize("Hello")
print normalize("ratty")
print normalize("SAS") == normalize("QBQ")
```

once you do that you can simply compare the normalized versions

```
def can_transform(s1,s2):
    return normalize(s1) == normalize(s2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pulled from [Understanding isomorphic strings algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465669/understanding-isomorphic-strings-algorithm)

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

def isomorphic(a, b):
    a_idxs, b_idxs = defaultdict(set), defaultdict(set)
    for idx, ((a_grp, a_vals), (b_grp, b_vals)) in enumerate(zip(groupby(a), groupby(b))):
        if sum(1 for _ in a_vals) != sum(1 for _ in b_vals):
            return False
            # ensure sequence is of same length
        if a_grp in a_idxs and b_idxs[b_grp] != a_idxs[a_grp] or\
           b_grp in b_idxs and a_idxs[a_grp] != b_idxs[b_grp]:
            return False
            # ensure previous occurrences are matching groups
        a_idxs[a_grp].add(idx)
        b_idxs[b_grp].add(idx)
        # save indexes for future checks
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code is this part:

```
if ... and t[i] in remap.values():
```

Since `remap.values()` is not a set or a dict, membership testing with `in` is a `O(n)` operation. This can slow down your code significantly if many characters have to be remapped.

You can speed this up by storing the remapped characters in a set:

```
def isIsomorphic():
    remap = dict()
    if s == t:
        return True
    if len(s) !=  len(t):
        return False

    remapped = set() # <- add this

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] not in remap.keys() and t[i] in remapped: # <- change this
            return False
        elif s[i] not in remap.keys():
            remap[s[i]] = t[i]
            remapped.add(t[i])
        else:
            if remap[s[i]] != t[i]:
                return False
    return True
```

Timed on two strings with 25 remapped characters and 1 million iterations, we notice a significant speedup:

```
original code  26.817705629997363 seconds
updated code   19.41265572499833  seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to check that characters from string1 are not in string2 and vice versa so use two dicts: a mapping `mapper`, and a reverse mapping `revmap` for this.

dict.[setdefault](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/setdefault) is doing a lot of the heavy lifting here - a useful method to know.

I got stuck in writing it with one long main expression, hence the style.

I only got this far by creating a few tests too.

```
def is_iso(s1, s2):
    mapper, revmap = {}, {}
    return (len(s1) == len(s2) 
            and all(((ch1 not in mapper and ch2 not in revmap) or
                     (ch1     in mapper and ch2     in revmap))
                    and ch2 == mapper.setdefault(ch1, ch2) 
                    and ch1 == revmap.setdefault(ch2, ch1)
                    for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))
           ), ' '.join(f'{fr}<->{to}' for fr, to in mapper.items())
```

The tests:

```
for s1, s2 in [("11", "aa"), ("ab", "aa"), ('abc', 'aaa'), ("foo", "bar"), 
               ("egg", "add"), ("paper", "title"), ('aabccd', '112334'), 
               ('aabccc', '112334')]:
    print( f'is_iso({s1!r}, {s2!r}) = %s \t# mappings: %s' % is_iso(s1, s2))
```

Output:

```
is_iso('11', 'aa') = True       # mappings: 1<->a
is_iso('ab', 'aa') = False      # mappings: a<->a
is_iso('abc', 'aaa') = False    # mappings: a<->a
is_iso('foo', 'bar') = False    # mappings: f<->b o<->a
is_iso('egg', 'add') = True     # mappings: e<->a g<->d
is_iso('paper', 'title') = True         # mappings: p<->t a<->i e<->l r<->e
is_iso('aabccd', '112334') = True       # mappings: a<->1 b<->2 c<->3 d<->4
is_iso('aabccc', '112334') = False      # mappings: a<->1 b<->2 c<->3
```